# How to determine exact mantissa length for Postgres double precision on any given platform

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, precision

How can I figure out the exact mantissa length for Postgres double precision on any given platform? I am imagining there might be a query I could use or a maybe a Postgres config variable I could see. I am expecting the mantissa length to be 53, but the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) states that it depends on the platform:

> The assumption that real and double precision have exactly 24 and 53 bits in the mantissa respectively is correct for IEEE-standard floating point implementations. On non-IEEE platforms it might be off a little, but for simplicity the same ranges of p are used on all platforms.

How can I determine the exact mantissa on my platform?

### Background

I am wanting to ensure that both my programming language (JavaScript) and my database (Postgres) have the same data format for floating point numbers. In my case, I chose the double precision data type on Postgres as I read in the documentation that it is the same format as JavaScript's (which is double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754). Here are links to the corresponding documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

Wanting to test out my solution, I tried to save a number on the edge of the mantissa length to Postgres in a double precision column with a value of `1.0000000000000002` but was uncessful. The number comes from the following calculation in JavaScript:

```js
console.log(1 + Number.EPSILON)
```

Unexpectedly, the database records the value as `1.0`. When I remove two decimal places and keep the trailing 2 so I have `1.00000000000002`, I am able to successfully save that float to the database. This is causing me issues as I expect a valid JavaScript number to be able to be saved to a double precision Postgres column.

Comment: Rather than experiment with adding small powers of 10, test with small powers of 2.

Comment: Good point, that would probably be a better way to experiment. My main goal with this question is to find a definitive answer on how many bits are used in the mantissa part - either documentation, source code, from a pg maintainer, etc.

Comment: How do you know the database recorded the value as `1.0` rather than recording the exact value (1+2^−52) but only showing it as `1.0`?

Comment: To get an exact answer, you'd have to read the documentation of the CPU manufacturer on how double precision is implemented there.

Comment: 1) How are you getting the `1.0` value from the database? 2) Read this [extra_float_digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS) and then check what that is set to with `show extra_float_digits ;`.

Comment: On Postgres 10, I can now see more of the decimal value after setting extra_float_digits to 3 (see [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/970864/set-extra-float-digits-3-everywhere-in-postgres)).